# Getting offsets after last committed offset in case of kafka simple consumer(0.8.2) restart?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

On calling getOffsetsBefore kafka simple consumer api(0.8.2) after consumer restart, offsets are returned which are already commited.

As per kafka code https://apache.googlesource.com/kafka/+/c27c768463a5dc6be113f2e5b3e00bf8d9d9d602/core/src/main/scala/kafka/server/KafkaApis.scala

The offsets we get, will of messages over a set of(one or more) log segments before given timestamp supplied in request.

- Is there any way(kafka mechanism ...excluding storing offsets to persistance store) to get next offset after last committed offset in case of kafka simple consumer api restart ?
- what is the purpose of commitOffsets api is we can't get the next offsets after last committed offset ?

Comment: could you please share the consumer code?

Comment: Below is code :                                                                                                                                Map<TopicAndPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets = new LinkedHashMap<TopicAndPartition, OffsetAndMetadata>();
  offsets.put(
    getTopicAndPartition(topic, partition),
    new OffsetAndMetadata(offset, metaData, System
      .currentTimeMillis()));
  OffsetCommitRequest commitRequest = new OffsetCommitRequest(
    brokerAndConsumer.getConsumer().clientId(), offsets,
    correlationId++, brokerAndConsumer.getConsumer().clientId(),
    (short)1);

Comment: // broker is kafka.cluster.Broker                                                                   Consumer consumer = new SimpleConsumer(broker.host(), broker.port(), 100000,
    64 * 1024, clientName);                                                                                       OffsetCommitResponse commitResponse = consumer
    .commitOffsets(commitRequest);
Collection<Object> errorResponses = commitResponse.errors().values();                   
if (commitResponse.hasError()) {
 .............
        }
}